# UITableViewController static cells not hiding, when table reload called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I implemented signup page using `UITableViewController` with static `UITablViewCells`. User can signup via two ways like custom(email, password, confirm password) and facebook. Once Signup success, showing profile page in the same `UITableViewController` - by hiding `UITableViewCell`s under `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method.

It is working when I am using custom signup. But the problem is when user tap facebook button

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            self.apiActivityIndicator.hideActivityIndicator(currentView: self.view) 
            if (error == nil){
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.postFacebookDataToServer(facebookData: self.dictionaryUserDetails)

                }
            }
```

it returns all the user details from facebook then I pass the facebook user details into our server by POST method using Alamofire

```
            Alamofire.request(urlFacebook, method: .post, parameters: parameterFacebook,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                self.isFacebookSuccess = true
                isUserLogIn = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set(isUserLogIn, forKey: Utility.userDefaultsType.kUserLog)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                if (isUserLogIn) {
                    self.loadProfileBottomView()
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }
```

after this I need to reload UITableView api response success. But UITableView is reloading the some of the UITableViewCells are still there, but when we scroll on top position, it is hiding and show exactly what I want. This is the

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    if (isUserLogIn) {
        print("MY Login Yes:\(isUserLogIn)")
        if cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_ImageLogin) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_LoginContent) ||  cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Facebook) ||  cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_OR) ||  cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Swipe) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_LoginEmail) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_LoginPassword) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_ButtonLogin) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_ForgotPassword) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_LoginEmptyCell) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Name) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Email) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Mobile) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Password) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_Confirm) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_ButtonRegister) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_RegisterEmptyCell) || cell.isEqual(tableViewCell_LastEmpty)    {
            return 0
        }
        else
        {
            return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initially, `heightForRowAt` in this method you won't get table view height. Are you sure got the height for that table view cell? and you didn't set any else return value? surly that method give you an error.

Comment: Are you storing all the cells in a variable? If so, that's not good way. In that case you can use `UIScrollView` instead of `UITableView`

Comment: @Mathi Arasan once the user login success, I reload the tableview, then it is update on func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat. It is working fine when I directly calling the Post server method on button action. But the problem is once FBSDKGraphRequest is called it didnt working. I think the issues is related any Block/queue

Comment: @Lal Krishna  as per my UI I have many UITextFields - avoiding keyboard issues I choose UITableViewController. It is working when I directly applying api server and its response is succes ith hide all signup UITableViewCells and showing user profile.  But when I implement FBSDKGraphRequest it didnt working

Comment: Why you called `dismiss` after FB success block? i think this is the issue

Comment: Sorry it not working after I comment dismiss method

Comment: All these codes are in same class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176710/discussion-between-lije-and-lal-krishna).